# How to reliably resolve a path relative to another?

Tags: php, path, relative-path, realpath

**In PHP, is there a built-in way to resolve a path relative to another?**

For example, given a `$baseDir` dir: `/home/ben/project`, the following `$path` should resolve to:

- `/foo/bar` → `/foo/bar`
- `../foo/bar`, →  `/home/ben/foo/bar`

---

Solutions that come to mind:

- Temporarily changing the current working directory, and using `realpath()`:

  ```php
  $currentDir = getcwd();
  chdir($baseDir);
  $resolvedPath = realpath($path);
  chdir($currentDir);

  return $resolvedPath;
  ```

  This solution is a bit tedious.
- Checking if the path is absolute, if not, using `realpath()`:

  ```php
  if ($path[0] === '/') {
      return $path;
  }

  return realpath($currentDir . '/' . $path);
  ```

  This solution is not cross-platform; making it safely cross-platform may not be as trivial as it looks.

Last but not least, `realpath()` returns `false` when the path does not exist, which is not taken into account in the above codes, and may be a problem in some use cases.

Did I miss something?

Comment: why you think your second solution is not cross-platform?

Comment: @GiacomoM Because on Windows, paths may start with `C:\ `, not `/`. And I'm not sure about other OSes.

Comment: PHP does have a constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR that is cross-platform

Comment: The directory separator is not the problem, `/` does work on Windows, too. The problem is reliably checking if a path is absolute or relative.

Comment: Still do not understand why you think is not cross-platform

Comment: To check if path is absolute or relative check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392274/checking-for-relative-vs-absolute-paths-urls-in-php